Can I use "we're on the way" to talk about "we're here to tell you something"?
I'm going to use "we're on the way" to say "we're coming to tell you and offer you something in writing email letter",so will it be ok to use? Is it correct? I want to know whether I can use it like this or not. Please answer me as fast as possible.I haven't done my assignment yet.

You have a whole line of words that are not punctuated well. This is important to sort out, because my first thought was, what set of words are you actually asking for help on?


we're on the way to talk


we're coming to tell you and offer you something

Here you are informing the other party about your current whereabouts and the things you will be discussing when you reach the place.
The second one is fine, but the first one isn't great.  This would be better:
We're on our way to your place to talk about ...
Such notifications are more likely used in a phone call or instant messaging.   Emails tend to be for more advance plans.
